# Downscaling WPF panel children

Tags: wpf, user-controls, panels

I am trying to change a project I was asssigned to at work and I ran into problems with one task. What I need to do is to create a NavigationBar component that will show dynamically created buttons (based on a list of available screens). The width of the button is not static and should be adapted to the button text (width is text width plus some static margins). The problem is that this control will be resized and should downscale the buttons accordingly - this means font size and therefore text width. This could theoretically be implemented using Viewbox, but I don't think I can do that when every button has different width based on its text. The height of the buttons is static.

For example

- On start, the width of the component is 100% (width of buttons plus some marings) every button is diplayed in full width with some default font size.
- When the width gets to 120%, the size of the buttons doesn't change as they were full size before
- When the width gets to 80%, the button text size is downscaled to 80% (by changing font size) so the buttons fit.

Part of this is already implemented by using the Viewbox in button template, but I should enhance the component by allowing different text widths within the buttons. This means buttons should have no MaxWidth, Width should be auto and MinWidth should be scaled by Width of the control itself. Also scaling down the container of the buttons doesn’t scale its children. Maybe I should implement my own panel with its own logic ? Also the problem is that the control should just shrink the buttons when scaled down and not widen them when scaled up.

I am really not sure where even start with this and after a more than a day of unsuccessful googling and prototyping I will be thankful for every little push forward.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I need to maintain the height of the buttons so I can't simply insert the buttons container into a ViewBox. Also, if I configure the ViewBox to shrink only vertically, the text becomes disproportional.

Comment: Why not just put all the buttons in one ViewBox?

Comment: That would be a great solution if I didn't need to maintain the height of the buttons (which I forgot to mention in the question initially). AFAIK with ViewBox, the buttons are also downsized horizontally or the text becomes disproportional. Or is there a way to change the behavior of the Viewbox ?

Comment: You can set size bounds for ViewBox itself, then it will stop scaling at some points. The text always maintains proportions, I think.